# Checkbox doesnt update database in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I used this code to get some choices from a checkbox to store data in a table with format nic,ModuleID.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty");
mysql_select_db("mis", $conn);
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$nic= $_SESSION['nic'];

if (is_array($variable)) {    
  foreach ($variable as $MID) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student_module(nic, MID) VALUES('$nic', '$MID')";
    $results = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
  }
}
//...
?>
```

But the table doesnt get update. Why?

Comment: What's `$variable`? And the mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Because `$variable` is not an array

Comment: can you echoing variable and query and check it out your variable is correct or not?

Comment: im not sure,i took that code fromsomewhere.the name of the checkboxgroup i take the checkbox values from is module.what code should iwrite to make it right?

Comment: yes im using session star

Comment: try `student_module(\`nic\`, \`MID\`)`

Comment: 1) Have you tried replacing `'$nic', '$MID'` with dummy data just to see if you DB code works? 2) try using `VALUES(".$nic.",".$MID.")"`

Comment: The line `$sql = "INSERT INTO` apparently exposes you to an SQL injection attack. To prevent this kind of thing, the `mysql_query` command you are using is deprecated in the newest versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for us to tell why it is not updating.

put an else statement in place

```
else {
echo 'not an array'
}
```

then check the POST data for your checkbox array. make sure it contains what you are expecting... If not post your HTML checkboxes.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Also in the code you provided there is not $variable set...